# ScrollIntoView is not a function

Tags: puppeteer

I have this code that iterates over table rows and on every row there is a Text that is checked if it matches and a checkbox that is checked if the text matches and the checkbox is not checked yet.

My problem is that I have the "children" elementHandle but it does not have the scrollIntoView() function. I can click the checkbox and it gets checked most of the time, but when it is out of the view it does not get checked.

I am running puppeteer in headless mode.

```
async function SelectVehicleType(vehicleType = undefined) {
  // If nothing selected as vehicleType the first one will be selected
  let example = await page.$$('.vehicle_select_table_tr'); // Get all table rows
  for (let element of example) { // Loop over table rows
    let innerText = await page.evaluate(e => e.getAttribute("vehicle_type"), element); // Get text from table row
    if (vehicleType == innerText.trim() || vehicleType == undefined) { // Check if vehicleType is right
      console.log('SelectVehicleType vehicle found:', vehicleType);
      let children = await element.$('td:nth-child(1)>input');
      if (await (await children.getProperty('checked')).jsonValue()) { // if checkbox is already checked continue
        debugFlow('Vehicle checkboox already checked... continue for loop');
        continue;
      }
      debugFlow('focus checkbox:');
      // THIST DOES NOT WORK \/
      await children.scrollIntoView(); // scroll checkbox into view so it can be checked
      await children.focus();
      debugFlow('click checkbox:');
      await children.click();

      await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 500));
      let checkboxChecked;
      try {
        checkboxChecked = await (await children.getProperty('checked')).jsonValue()
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('checkboxChecked check failed...');
        throw new Error(error);
      }
      if (!checkboxChecked) { // checkbox is not checked
        return SelectVehicleType(vehicleType); //call itself again
      } else {
        debugFlow('Checkbox correct checked :)');
        return new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 500));
      }
    }
  };
}
```